# how to display a list of images on one side of the split pane

Tags: java, user-interface, imagej

I want to make a split pane where on the left hand side it displays a list of images, and once you click on those images it should then display the image in a bigger size on the right hand side. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this because I can't seem to create a list of images (image icons) on the left hand side of the split pane. I can read and open .dcm images (using ImageJ) and they are displayed in the internal frame but I can't make it work in split panes. If anyone has a general solution on how I could make this work it would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

So this is my code that displays a list of questions on the left side and then more information about it on the right hand side of the split panes. I was wondering how can I make the left hand side a list of image icons. So that if an image is clicked it is displayed on to the right hand side.

```
public class FrequentQuestions implements ActionListener, InternalFrameListener{

private int openFrameCount;
private JDesktopPane desk;
private JTextArea Tarea;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private BufferedReader in ;
JPanel panelQuestions = new JPanel();
JPanel panelAnswers = new JPanel();
JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
JTextPane tPane = new JTextPane();
String file ="";
//private FrequentQuestions quest;
JSplitPane pane ;
MyInternalFrame frame;


public FrequentQuestions(JDesktopPane desktop) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    desk = desktop;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(frame == null || frame.getParent() == null){
    frame = new MyInternalFrame("Frequently Asked Questions");

    String [] options = {"How to open/save images", "What formats can SAD Imaging open", "How to show information about an image"};
    JList list = new JList(options);
    //list.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    //panelQuestions.add(list);
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false)
                return;

            String [] options2 = {"hello","bye"};
            JList list2 = new JList(options2);
            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();


            if (list.isSelectionEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("list selection is empty!");
            }

                int index = ((JList)e.getSource()).getSelectedIndex();
                if(index == 0){
                    //panelAnswers.removeAll();
                    file = "";
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("openSave.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String line;

                    try {
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            file += line;
                            file +="\n";

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tPane.setText(file);
                    System.out.println("I am outputting!");
                }
                else if(index == 1){
                    //panelAnswers.removeAll();
                    file = "";
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("format.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String line;
                    //String file = ""; 
                    try {
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            file += line;
                            file +="\n";

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tPane.setText(file);
                    System.out.println("2nd item selected");

                }
                else{
                    //panelAnswers.removeAll();
                    file = "";
                    try {
                        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("showInfo.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String line;

                    try {
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            file += line;
                            file +="\n";

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tPane.setText(file);
                    System.out.println("3rd item selected");
                }

        }

    });

    JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(list,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(tPane,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scroll1, scroll);
    pane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    pane.setOpaque(true);

    panelQuestions.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(259,50));
    panelQuestions.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    panelAnswers.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,30));
    pane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    pane.setDividerLocation(290);
    scroll1.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    //Border border = new Border();
    //scroll1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    frame.add(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    desk.add(frame);

     try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e1) {

    }
    }
    else{
        try {
            //frame.setIcon(true);
            //frame.setMaximizable(true);

            frame.setSelected(true);
            frame.moveToFront();
            //frame.toFront();
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
    public MyInternalFrame(String title) {
        super(title, true,true, true, true);
        setSize(800,500);

        // Set the window's location.
        setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition * openFrameCount);
    }
}

@Override
public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    frame = null;
}

@Override
public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    frame = null;
}

@Override
public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: You're going to have a lot better luck on here if you demonstrate effort.

Comment: @leigero I added the code that I am working one.

Comment: I recommend that you use JavaFX for that would be really easy. I am working on a very similar project. But the trick is to create buttons and load each button with the image, then launch it.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun I had a look into JavaFX but I don't understand how to use it with eclipse- with the code I already have.

Comment: @selena, I made that comment when your question had no code, so I thought you were planning steps. Since you are using swing there is no need to use JavaFX. I will look at your code later today.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun okay thanks. I have it basically all laid out, like it will take in ImagePlus img (image), where these images are opened and read in the main file and then I just don't how to set the left hand side of pane (the jlist) to take images instead of strings. I am basically just looking for a general example on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //Create the list of images and put it in a scroll pane.
    list = new JGridPanel(1, imageNames.length);
    JScrollPane pictureScrollPane = new JScrollPane(picture);

    for (int i=0; i < imageNames.length; i++) {
        picture = new JButton();
        picture.setBackground(Color.black);
        ImageIcon img = createImageIcon("images/" + "#FileName" + ".gif");
        picture.setIcon(img);
        list.setComponent(picture, 0, i);

    }

    //Create a split pane with the two scroll panes in it.
    splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            list, pictureScrollPane);
    splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
    splitPane.setDividerLocation(150);

    //Provide minimum sizes for the two components in the split pane.
    Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(100, 50);
    list.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
    pictureScrollPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);

    //Provide a preferred size for the split pane.
    splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
```

And use [this class](https://code.google.com/p/screenshot-maven-plugin/source/browse/trunk/screenshot-maven-plugin-parent/swingset3-demo-app/src/main/java/com/sun/swingset3/demos/JGridPanel.java?r=172) for the JGridPanel.

Comment: So in the for loop it creates a list of images to be displayed but when I put into the splitPane it doesn't display anything. Cause I am trying to do this with imageJ images. I converted .dcm to ImageIcon but it doesn't display anything.